# Struts2 grid filter column with dynamic list (drop down) not supported

Tags: jqgrid, struts2, filter, grid

I am unable to get Struts2 grid filter column with dynamic list (drop down) to work.
The code is below. I am using struts grid 2.2. Tried edittype="select" on column. no luck :(

```
<sjg:grid id="unAssignedTable" 
                    ...


                    filter="true"
                    **filterOptions="{ stringResult :true,
                                     searchOnEnter : true,
                                    enableClear : true}"**

                ..
                    >


                    ...
                    <sjg:gridColumn name="countryDescription" index="countryDescription" title="Country" sortable="true" search="true" edittype="select"  />
                    ....
                </sjg:grid>
```

Basically want search filter on shipType column as here http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/searching/search_toolbar/default.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy once we know the parameter (dataInit) and syntax.

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="test" index="test" title="Test" sortable="true" width="90"
                                        searchoptions="{   dataInit:function(elem) {myfunction(elem) }  }" />
```

Comment: how did you managed to get list in drop-down list, i am unable to show data in list but in string form as {"helpDeskUsers":"success","userList":[{"departments":null,"helper_name":"arvin","helper_value":null,"user_level":null},{"departments......

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you know the id attribute of your filter element.  Assuming you do, just add the necessary HTML code using something like JQuery to the element.

Comment: Thanks. Have managed to get the list into the dropdown. But I am yet to understand how to trigger the filter onChange of select dropdown